# Shortest-Path Search - using Edge types [NetworkX, igraph]

Tags: python, graph, igraph, networkx, shortest-path

I'm using Directed MultiGraph as data structure (between two nodes may be more than one edge).

I'd like to assign edges in my MultiDiGraph different types. For example, edge (u,v_1) can be type_1, another edge (u,v_2) can be type 2.

After build this data structe I'd like to find shortest-path, but path must contain edges only certain type (type 1, for example). Is it possible in NetworkX or python-igraph libraries?

Comment: In igraph, set the weights of the edges according to the types. I.e. set all type-1 edge weights to one, and all other edge weights to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Gabor Csardi in networkx, to add edges of type 1: add attributes type_1 with the value you want, and add attribute type_2 to maximum int (to be ignored in the shortest path computation as if it does not exist). Similarly, do the same to create edge of type_2.

The following code shows a simple graph to manifest the idea where the shortest path from 1 to 4 is shorter through 2 in type_1 edge and shorter through 3 in type_2 edge.

```
g=nx.MultiDiGraph()
g.add_edge(1,2,type1=2,type2=sys.maxint) # add edge of type 1 
g.add_edge(1,2,type1=sys.maxint,type2=3) # add edge of type 2
g.add_edge(2,4,type1=2,type2=sys.maxint)
g.add_edge(2,4,type1=sys.maxint,type2=4)
g.add_edge(3,4,type1=3,edge_type2=sys.maxint)
g.add_edge(3,4,type1=sys.maxint,type2=1)
g.add_edge(1,3,type1=sys.maxint,type2=1)
print nx.shortest_path(g,1,4,weight='type1')
print nx.shortest_path(g,1,4,weight='type2')
```

> The result:

```
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 3, 4]
```

Also, find attached the created graph to be able to visualize it easier.[image]